# BeagleBone can't boot with systemd

Tags: yocto, systemd, beagleboneblack

I would like to make an image with yocto for beaglebone black.
My project requires the uses of systemd.

I have made an image, I followed this tutorial: https://jumpnowtek.com/beaglebone/BeagleBone-Systems-with-Yocto.html
It works fine, but it uses sysVinit. Here is no problem (thanks jumpnowtek).
I searched how can use systemd and I have made some changes in the local.conf file.
The relevant part of my local.conf:

```
DISTRO_FEATURES = "systemd ext2 usbhost sysVinit ${DISTRO_FEATURES_LIBC}"

DISTRO_FEATURES_BACKFILL_CONSIDERED += "sysVinit pulseaudio opengl"

PREFERRED_PROVIDER_jpeg = "libjpeg-turbo"

VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_init_manager = " systemd"
VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_initscripts = "systemd-compat-units"

PREFERRED_VERSION_linux-stable = "4.9.%"
```

I didn't make any changes in the main part of config as you can find in the tutorial. I added some application to the distro only. (i.e. nginx, vim, gdb nothing special)

I could build with this local.conf it was succesfull, but the beaglebone can't boot.

The symptoms:
the 4 leds are blinking at the usb power, and the ethernet interface yellow/green led blinking also. But the HDMI doesn't have output, and a can't find the bone on the network. It look like the bone stag in the boot process. But I don't know, it's only tip.

Is anybody who met same issue?
The systemd required something, special settings?
I made missconfigure? Is it make errors at the compile time?

Thanks for answers.

EDIT: I close out hardware issue because I can use other image with same devices

Comment: What you see on the console? Any logs? Or u-boot itself didn't boot?

Comment: Nothing.The screen stay black.  I try looking something rules in the leds blinking like raspberry but I can't recognize any rhythm or something. It use u-boot

Comment: UART debug cable connected ? Do you have console logs?

Comment: Did you enable cgroups in the kernel configuration? I had an issue with the booting process stopping due to this. Again, A FTDI cable helps a lot in detecting such problems.